# Nested foreach loop conversion to lambda or linq

Tags: sql, linq, foreach, lambda, nested-loops

I am trying much to convert it to lambda but could not succeed. Is there any method to convert to linq or lambda?

```
foreach (var tempitem in mbsRateTempList)
{
    foreach (var Saveditem in mbsSavedRecordList)
    {
        if (tempitem.MbsSecurityId == Saveditem.MbsSecurityId && tempitem.CouponRate == Saveditem.CouponRate
               && tempitem.SettlementMonth.Month == Saveditem.SettlementMonth.Month && tempitem.Price == Saveditem.Price)
        {
            TobeDeletedIds.Add(Saveditem.Id);
            MatchedIdsInTempList.Add(tempitem.TempId);
            //mbsSavedRecordList[0].ObjectState=Repository.Pattern.Base.Infrastructure.ObjectState.
        }
        //else
        //{

        //}
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please give examples of the data you're using, the code entities you have and the error that you got. It is OK to edit your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `Join` on anonymous types containing all relevant properties:

```
var objectsToAdd = from tempitem in mbsRateTempList
                   join saveditem mbsSavedRecordList
                   on new { tempitem.MbsSecurityId,  tempitem.CouponRate, tempitem.SettlementMonth.Month, tempitem.Price } 
                   equals new { saveditem.MbsSecurityId,  saveditem.CouponRate, saveditem.SettlementMonth.Month, saveditem.Price } 
                   select new { tempitem, saveditem };

foreach(var x in objectsToAdd)
{
    TobeDeletedIds.Add(x.saveditem.Id);
    MatchedIdsInTempList.Add(x.tempitem.TempId);
}
```